# HasMany Multiple Selects not working Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hello I am trying to select data from multiple tables in HasMany but its not working. Here is my code

```
class UserInfo extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'user_info';
    public $primaryKey = 'user_id';


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'type' => 'RIGHT',
            'fields' => array('User.user_id','User.email','User.active')
        )


    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'UserCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'UserCategory',
            'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => array('user_id = UserCategory.user_id')
            //'order' => 'UserCategory. DESC'

        )


);



    public function getUserDetails($user_id){
        $this->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        return $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'UserInfo.user_id' => $user_id
            ),
            'contain' => array(
                'User', 'UserCategory.Category',

            )

        ));

    }
```

If I try to fetch the data from another table which has `user_id` in it like this

```
public $hasMany = array(
            'UserCategory' => array(
                'className' => 'UserCategory',
                'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
                'dependent' => true,
                'conditions' => array('user_id = UserCategory.user_id')
                //'order' => 'UserCategory. DESC'

            ),

            'Skill' => array(
                'className' => 'Skill',
                'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
                'dependent' => true


            )
    );
```

It doesn't fetch. When I run sql dump. It doesn't run query at all. So Meaning I am unable to get the data from **Skills** Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read the docs thoroughly for [containable](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) in cakephp 2. In summary, when you use containable like :

```
'contain' => array(
    'User', 'UserCategory.Category',
)
```

You can add your desired Model in it like in your case this will help you :

```
'contain' => array(
    'User', 'UserCategory.Category', 'Skill'
)
```

Containable helps to filter your find() data as per your requirement.